# lwp-request in shell: how to make POST request with body?

Tags: shell, http-post, lwp

I use simple shell script to test some http server that process POST requests.
Usually it looks like:

```
echo "param1=value1&param2=value2" | POST localhost/service
```

But now I want to pass also some json in POST **body** and that's where I missing point completely.

*man POST* and google did't help much also.

Seems it must be either very simple or completely impossible.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either I'm missing something, or you should do

```
$ echo -n '{"json":"data"}' | POST -c "application/json" 'http://localhost/service?param1=value1&param2=value2'
```

If you need to put those parameters not as GET, but as POST as well, then look up multipart form data.

Comment: You probably mean  `echo -n '{"json":"data"}' | POST -c "application/json" localhost/service`  That's good, but still leave me with problem how to pass request parameters  `"param1=value1&param2=value2"`

Comment: Yeah, I got it. The only chance to pass both body and params to http request is to use GET parameters. That's my lack of http requests understanding, thanks for help. Can't upvote yet, lack reputation.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to pass content type using **-c**:

```
POST -c application/json
```

Comment: Wouldn't you be so kind to specify exact command line look?   `echo "param1=value1&param2=value2" | POST -c application/json "some body content here" localhost/service`   didn't work.